# Implied volatility calculation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

With the comments from the answer, I rewrote the code below (math.1p(x)->math.log(x)), which now should work and give a good approximation of the volatility.

I am trying to create a short code to calculate the implied volatility of a European Call option. I wrote the code below:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

norm.cdf(1.96)
#c_p - Call(+1) or Put(-1) option
#P - Price of option
#S - Strike price
#E - Exercise price
#T - Time to expiration
#r - Risk-free rate

#C = SN(d_1) - Ee^{-rT}N(D_2)


def implied_volatility(Price,Stock,Exercise,Time,Rf):
    P = float(Price)
    S = float(Stock)
    E = float(Exercise)
    T = float(Time)
    r = float(Rf)
    sigma = 0.01
    print (P, S, E, T, r)
    while sigma < 1:
        d_1 = float(float((math.log(S/E)+(r+(sigma**2)/2)*T))/float((sigma*(math.sqrt(T)))))
        d_2 = float(float((math.log(S/E)+(r-(sigma**2)/2)*T))/float((sigma*(math.sqrt(T)))))
        P_implied = float(S*norm.cdf(d_1) - E*math.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(d_2))
        if P-(P_implied) < 0.001:
            return sigma
        sigma +=0.001
    return "could not find the right volatility"

print implied_volatility(15,100,100,1,0.05)
```

This yields: 0.595 volatility which should be somewhere 0.3203. That is a huge difference...

I know this is not a fast method by any means, I just want to demonstrate how the principle works, but I am not able to calculate a good approximation.
For some reason when I call the function it gives me really bad approximation of the actual implied volatility which I calculated using a Matlab Program and the following webpage: [Implied Volatility](http://www.option-price.com/implied-volatility.php). Could anyone please help me to figure out where I made the mistake?

Comment: My guess would be integer operations rather than float. Have you tried casting all variables to float explicitly?

Comment: All of them should be floats and I just checked them.

Comment: If anyone else gets stuck try this [link]https://codearmo.com/blog/implied-volatility-european-call-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems I see, none of which are directly python related:

1. You are using `log1p(x)`, which is the natural logarithm of `1+x`, while you actually want `log(x)`, which is the natural logarithm of `x` (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black.E2.80.93Scholes_formula)).
2. An option price of `100` is way to high considering the other parameters. Try to calculate the implied volatility for a price of `10` - which should be about `0.18` both by your program and the calculator you linked.

Comment: Thank you, you managed.1) It was my mistake not noticing that earlier. 2) the price was I think 15. But now it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, the result of `5 / 2` is `2`.  It uses floor division.  To fix that, make every number a float.  In your `implied_volatility` function, change `P = Price` to `P = float(Price)`, `S = Stock` to `S = float(Stock)`, etc.

Comment: I have just done what you said, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: or just do `from __future__ import division` as first import

Comment: @MaxNoe: True; I had forgotten that.